# What does the phrase "rolling green" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of the phrase **rolling green** in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game Pixel Pro Golf?

> You should watch out for wild winds and ***rolling greens***!

Here is a description of the game from [Apple App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pixel-pro-golf/id1534171570):

> Play through 20 gorgeous pixelated courses, each carefully crafted
> with a unique style and conditions, as you try to become the best of
> the best.
>
> Use the simple controls to aim, change club and swing. Then watch your
> ball head down stunning pixel fairways.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rolling https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/green_2

Comment: What Colleen said, definition 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a golf course, each hole is surrounded by a patch (about ten metres across?) of grass cut shorter than elsewhere, called the *green*.  The green is relatively smooth, but generally not flat; it may even undulate ("rolling").